# Where criteria is not working on populate in waterline

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-orientdb

I am using waterline and waterlinhe-orientdb.
I have user and order vertex classes and bought edge class
User ---Bought-->Orders
I am trying to apply Where criteria on populate.
But is not working on populate.
Here is my code

```
var CREDIT_CARD = 1; 
User.find({id:userid}).populate('boughts',{where:{payment_method:CREDIT_CARD}})
```

Schema

```
USER = {
    identity: 'user',
    connection: 'myLocalOrient',
    attributes:{
    status: { type:"integer", columnName:"status"},
    fname: { type:'string'},
    lname: { type:'string'},
    boughts: {collection: 'orders',through: 'boughts',via: 'user',dominant: true}
};

Bought = {
    identity:'boughts',
    connection: 'myLocalOrient',
    attributes:{
        status:{type:'integer', columnName:'status'},
        buyers:{
                  columnName: 'out',
                  type: 'string',
                  foreignKey: true,
                  references: 'users',
                  on: 'id',
                  onKey: 'id',
                  via: 'orders'
        },
        orders:{
                  columnName: 'in',
                  type: 'string',
                  foreignKey: true,
                  references: 'orders',
                  on: 'id',
                  onKey: 'id',
                  via: 'buyer'
        }
      }
};

Order = {
    identity:'orders',
    connection: 'myLocalOrient',
    attributes:{
            status:{type:'integer',columnName:'status'},
            payment_method:{type:'integer', columnName:'payment_method'},
            boughts:{collection:'users', through:'boughts',via:'orders'}
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

9me, from your model definition I can see you are using many-to-many **through** associations which are not yet officially supported by Waterline. This means that some functionality may not be fully operational and that some errors may occur. For more details read [When Many-to-Many Through Associations release? #705](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/705).

Your query is also not correct:

```
var CREDIT_CARD = 1; 
User.find({id:userid}).populate('boughts',{where:{payment_method:CREDIT_CARD}})
```

The criteria in `.populate()` does not take the key `where`.

Here's an example from the [documentation](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/query.md#populate):

```
// Collection Filtering
User.find()
.populate('foo', { type: 'bar', limit: 20 })
.exec(function(err, users) {});
```

So, in your case you should use:

```
var CREDIT_CARD = 1; 
User.find({ id: userid }).populate('boughts', { payment_method: CREDIT_CARD })
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll Try it. and I have an other question How can I run this query in waterline `SELECT COUNT(@rid), SUM(total_amount) FROM bills` ? Thanks again